# Escape the need for "sudo" for a bash alias

Tags: bash, arch-linux

I made an alias to shut down my arch linux computer. It runs `sudo shutdown -h -P now`. I run it and am asked for my password and then it shuts down and powers off. Is there a way I can get this to run without it needing root privileges to run?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`visudo`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/visudo) to edit your `/etc/sudoers` file and create an entry that allows your username to run `shutdown` without a password.

```
username hostname = NOPASSWD: /path/to/shutdown
```

See [`man sudo`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo) and [`man sudoers`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/sudoers) for more information.

Comment: Could I use a similar method to allow a user to update, but not install packages? that is, allow nopassword for `pacman -Syu` but not for `pacman` in general?

Comment: @Seamus: Yes, from `man sudoers`: "If a Cmnd has associated command line arguments, then the arguments in the Cmnd must match exactly those given by the user on the command line (or match the wildcards if there are any)."

Answer (score 0):

Why not add yourself to the `power` group?

`sudo gpasswd -a your_username power`